# How do I move the tip of a branch back 3 commits?

Tags: git

I would like to split my work into two branches, so I would like to assign a new branch name to the current tip and move my current branch name back 3 commits. The 3 new commits  have not yet been pushed.

I currently have this:

```
branch1                     F - G - H  
                           /
origin/branch1    C - D - E
                 /
master      A - B
```

And I would like this:

```
branch2                              F - G - H  
                                    /
branch1, origin/branch1    C - D - E
                          /
master               A - B
```

I already created `branch2`:

```
git checkout -b cleanup_exchanges
```

Could you please advise me on the next step, to take `branch1` back a few commits without moving `branch2`?

Comment: @Liam yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branch is nothing but a pointer to a commit, so you can freely move the `branch1` pointer to any other commit.

This should work

```
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard origin/branch1
```

or to go some N commits back:

```
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard branch1~3
```

Answer (score 1):

From this source: [https://opensource.com/article/18/6/git-reset-revert-rebase-commands](http://Let%27s%20start%20with%20the%20Git%20command%20reset.%20Practically,%20you%20can%20think%20of%20it%20as%20a%20%22rollback%22%E2%80%94it%20points%20your%20local%20environment%20back%20to%20a%20previous%20commit.%20By%20%22local%20environment,%22%20we%20mean%20your%20local%20repository,%20staging%20area,%20and%20working%20directory.)

Let's start with the Git command reset. Practically, you can think of it as a "rollback"—it points your local environment back to a previous commit. By "local environment," we mean your local repository, staging area, and working directory.

```
$ git log --oneline
b764644 File with three lines
7c709f0 File with two lines
9ef9173 File with one line
```

The Reset Command:

```
$ git reset 9ef9173 (using an absolute commit SHA1 value 9ef9173)
```

or

```
$ git reset current~2 (using a relative value -2 before the "current" tag)
```

Then you can check the logs again

```
$ git log --oneline
9ef9173 File with one line
```

In your case you have the origin/branch1 as a reference and you can do this:

```
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard origin/branch1
```

In conclusion, you have different ways to go back in time in a branch, even using a non-conventional way as:

```
git checkout -b 9ef9173 (using an absolute commit SHA1 value 9ef9173)
```

This will create a new branch an then

```
git checkout branch1
git merge 9ef9173
```